# Swift sending Data Via Segue To ViewController Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uistoryboardsegue

I am having trouble trying to send data to a second viewcontroller. More specifically, I am parsing a website and putting specific elements into an object. From there i am trying to send the response to another view controller. I have done this already once in the app, but i am not sure what i am doing wrong this time.

VC1:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
        guard let assignments = sender as AnyObject as? [Assignment],

            let sendMe = segue.destination as? ClassTableViewController
            else { return }

        sendMe.myAssignments = assignments

    }
    let classResponse = try ClassParser(innerHTML)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowClass", sender: classResponse.classAssignments) //segue to ClassTableViewController
```

ClassTableViewController uses that object to display more info. However, the error keeps coming back as `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.`, meaning that the object contents isnt being sent properly.
ClassTableViewController:

```
class ClassTableViewController: HeaderViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var classTableView: UITableView!

    var myAssignments: [Assignment]!
    override func viewDidLoad() {



    }



}
    extension ClassTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return myAssignments.count //ERROR HERE. The variable is empty
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ClassViewCell", for: indexPath)// as! NineWeekCellTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = myAssignments[indexPath.row].name
      cell.detailTextLabel?.text = myAssignments[indexPath.row].grade
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Your error does not happen in these lines of code. Please post the code where the error happens

Comment: @FangmingNing Ok i added the second controller above

Answer (score 0):

Your error happens because you are force unwrapping a optional object and that happens to be a `nil`. From your code, the only place you do force unwrapping in your `prepareForSegue` method, where you are passing `sender` after a force unwrap. So first, change your `prepareForSegue` method to this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let assignments = sender as AnyObject as? [Assignment],
        let sendMe = segue.destination as? ClassTableViewController
        else { return }

    sendMe.myAssignments = assignments
}
```

I suspect that your `classResponse.classAssignments` is nil, so when you call

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowClass", sender: classResponse.classAssignments)`

You force unwrapped the nil value and error happend

Comment: any other ideas?

Comment: @yzet00 Oh, I see. So where are you adding data into your `myAssignments` array

Comment: in the prepare segue. It is set to assignments.

Comment: @yzet00 Oh I see. Okay, add this piece of code in your `viewDidLoad`. This piece of code will print out your array to see if it is nil or not. Also verify the source array in your VC1's `prepareForSegue` method: `dump(myAssignments)`

Comment: it is nil return "-nil". Thats what I thought. The value isn't transferring over.

Comment: @yzet00 Now in your `repareForSegue` check if source array `assignments` is nil or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148001/discussion-between-yzet00-and-fangming-ning).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there were two segues going to the same view controller. Deleted one and the variables were passed successfully.